# Install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I used  curl to download the link

```
curl -O http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz
```

Then I extract the archive to it with these commands:

```
sudo tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
```

but I got an error:

```
root@localhost:/tmp# curl -O http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   327  100   327    0     0   1193      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1193
root@localhost:/tmp# sudo mkdir /opt/tomcat
root@localhost:/tmp# sudo tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: But I think helping people is the intention of this community right. I don't understand why there is a downvote for my answer. It indeed helps this guy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your tomcat download link is not valid.

Using the following link to curl the latest release

http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.27/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.27.tar.gz

Or if you wanna to use v8.5.5, here is the working url

https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz